# HttpRequestValidationException showing YSOD despite customErrors section

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, custom-errors

we've modified our customErrors section to protect against the recent ASP.NET vulnerability.

Our problem is, that HttpRequestValidationException's are now causing a YSOD's to be shown, other exceptions and page not found errors are showing our custom error page.

If we change the redirectMode to ResponseRedirect everything works fine.

This is our modified section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
```

This question has nothing to do with the recent ASP.NET vulnerability!It's about the ResponseRewrite redirectMode in combination with HttpRequestValidationException's. We know there will soon be a patch and that we could change back to ResponseRedirect.

Kind regards, Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your error page generates an error.

Make sure you turn off request validation on your error page. <%@ Page  ValidateRequest="false" %>

You then of course need to encode any user input that displays on your error page. eg. Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message)